# Why are at least three concurrent lines needed to specify a line bundle in 3D-Space?

Tags: geometry, vector-bundles, line-bundles

I am doing visual SLAM and learning about Bundle Adjustment. So I started reading about bundles and pencils in geometry and I understood the main concept:

*In geometry, a pencil is a family of geometric objects with a common property, for example the set of lines that pass through a given point in a plane, or the set of circles that pass through two given points in a plane. The common characteristic is that the pencil is completely determined by any two of its members.*

But the following confused me:

*Analogously, a set of geometric objects that are determined by any three of its members is called a bundle. Thus, the set of all lines through a point in three-space is a bundle of lines...*  [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_(geometry)#:%7E:text=Thus%2C%20the%20set%20of%20all%20lines%20through%20a%20point%20in%20three%2Dspace%20is%20a%20bundle%20of%20lines%2C%20any%20two%20of%20which%20determine%20a%20pencil%20of%20lines.)

Two intersecting lines in 3D-space specify a point (x,y,z) which we can then use to find all other lines that go through that point. So why isn't "*the set of all lines through a point in three-space*" a pencil instead of a bundle? In other words why is it that at least 3 lines going through the point are needed to specify all other lines going through the same point? shouldn't two be enough?

Comment: Interesting... should I suggest the edit on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_(geometry)) page then?

Comment: Never mind--it's been so long since I read the source for what I was thinking, I'm no longer sure what I saw there. It was in projective geometry where it's sometimes easy to forget how many dimensions you're talking about.